# Error while uploading a JSON file to Amazon SQS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I have the follwing code which basically tries to write a .json file to SQS

```
import json
import uuid
import time
import boto.sqs
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage

sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")
queue = sqs.get_queue("Demon")
json_fileone=open('emp.json')  ## this is only one JSON file 
dataone=json.load(json_fileone)

print dataone
[queue.write(queue.new_message(i)) for i in dataone]
print "File sent successfully to queue"
```

This uploads the desired emp.json file, what i need to do is run a loop on the number of file since i have emp1.json,emp2.json,emp3.json,emp4.json to SQS , and by default BOTO does a BASE64 encoding before sending... i need to send these files in the same format i.e '.json'

Comment: Try`[queue.write(queue.new_message(i)) for i in [dataone]]` Maybe`[queue.write(queue.new_message(i)) for i in dataone]`

Comment: yep... [queue.write(queue.new_message(i)) for i in dataone]  
this works...
but what if i have a n number of json files to send to queue ?

Comment: What's your data format?? What I said is just a wild guess. The correct code depend on your data. Give some data sample maybe.

Comment: the files i wanna upload are 5 json files,, and i need to upload them to the SQS, but by default boto encodes them before sending in base 64.. which i don't wanna... so i need two things to be done :
1. Upload a number of files { i guess a lil modification before inserting in for loop}
2. these .json files shoud be RawMessages() ...

Comment: Update your question, not comments.

Comment: updated my question @luoluo

Comment: Do you mean you want all the files in pattern `*json` go through the above process?

Comment: yes.. all the files with *.json should be uploaded via the above process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question and our comments, you need to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

```
import glob
json_files = glob.glob("*.json")
for json_file in json_files: 
    process_file(json_file)
```

So move your process to function `process_file`. Meanwhile use `with` statement to process files.

```
def process_file(json_file):
    sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")
    queue = sqs.get_queue("Demon")
    with open('emp.json') as json_fileone: 
        dataone=json.load(json_fileone)
        .....
```

Comment: yes.. it works.. and one more question... this uploads the json file and stores in SQS as individual objects .. is this actually the desired behaviour of queue ?

Comment: Well, I know little about SQS, maybe you should read the official docs, or search the error around.